# Feature Selection(How to interpret the results)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, feature-selection

Let's say i have a dataset and i want to select features which correspond to prediction result better than others. I have implemented some Feature Ranking tests and here are the results:

[image]

For prediction model I selected features with best "Mean" value.

```
X = oil_10[['Sidetrack Code','Well Type Code','Well Status  
Code','Producing Formation','Water Produced, bbl','County']]
```

Here is the prediction model result with "Best chosen features":

```
RandomForestRegressor
0.390502562474
```

And here is the result of prediction model with all dataset features without any selection:

```
RandomForestRegressor
0.741878611892
```

How to use Feature Ranking results to implement best prediction result?

Answer (score 0):

Well i've tried to solve my problem this way:
I just dropped the least important features(which had mean importance value less than 0.15) and the accuracy remained the same 75% but the prediction model works much faster now.